# Is it possible to offset the position of a single xtic/ytic?

Tags: gnuplot, coordinates

Is it possible to offset the position of a single xtic/ytic in gnuplot?

In my situation I have a (traditional style) x/y-axis and the xtic/ytic "0" ends up on the respective axis. Instead of the two "0"s (one for x one for y) I would like to have just a single "0" which is located south-west (bottom left) of the origin so that it does not interfere with the axis.

The code I use:

```
reset
set xrange [-5:5];
set yrange [-5:5];

set size ratio 1
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
set border 0

set grid x2tics y2tics noxtics noytics
set x2tics 0.5 format "" scale 0
set y2tics 0.5 format "" scale 0
set xtics axis 1 
set ytics axis 1 

set arrow 1 from 0,-5.3 to 0,5.3 lt -1 filled head
set arrow 2 from -5.3,0 to 5.3,0 lt -1 filled head

plot 1/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

**Code:**

```
### xtics, ytics only one zero
reset session
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]

set size ratio 1
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
set border 0

set grid x2tics y2tics noxtics noytics
set x2tics 0.5 format "" scale 0
set y2tics 0.5 format "" scale 0
set xtics axis 1 
set ytics axis 1 
set xtics add ("" 0)
set ytics add ("" 0)
set label 1 "0" at 0,0 offset -1.5,-0.5

set arrow 1 from 0,-5.3 to 0,5.3 lt -1 filled head
set arrow 2 from -5.3,0 to 5.3,0 lt -1 filled head

plot 1/0
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]